# Trigger description is too long error while updating my comment section

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm trying to update my changes in comment section of a trigger. When I add and try to compile it, I'm getting this error:

[image]

Even if I change the length of my comment, I'm still getting this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'description' refers to the section at the top, before the start of the PL/SQL code. The 'triggering code' begins at `begin`/`declare`.

```
create or replace trigger customer_trg
before insert or update or delete
on customer 
for each row
-- There is a limit to how much text you can place in this section.
-- More than 2000 chacacters in total will give ORA-04086.
begin
    null;
end customer_trg;
```

Move the comments block down into the code section:

```
create or replace trigger customer_trg
before insert or update or delete
on customer 
for each row
begin
-- Instead move the comments block down into the PL/SQL section here.
    null;
end customer_trg;
```